# Disable and Enable UIButton - XCode Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton

I have made an app that generates a random number and the user must enter a guess and click a button, GUESS to submit. All is working fine. However, I am simply trying to start the app with btnGuess disabled and enabled when a new game is started. The button will also be disabled when the user wins the game. So far, I have searched online and on here as to how you disabled/enable a UIButton and every answer I have found (most notably: button.enabled = false) does not seem to work. Please let me know what I am missing here. I have also tried button.enabled = NO; (which was another offered solution that does not work for me). Thanks.

```
import UIKit

class myViewController: UIViewController {

var guesses : UInt = 0
var number : UInt32 = 0
var inputGuess = 0


@IBOutlet weak var lblGuesses: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var lblGuessTitle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var lblOutput: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var txtInput: UITextField!

@IBAction func txtInput(sender: UITextField){

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    txtInput.enabled = false
    // btnGuess.enabled = false    //doesnt work



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func generateRandom() -> UInt32{
    return arc4random_uniform(100) + 1
}

func incrementGuesses(){
    ++guesses
    lblGuesses.text = String(guesses)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func btnGuess(sender: UIButton) {

    let inputGuess = txtInput.text.toInt()

    if UInt32(inputGuess!) > number{
        lblOutput.text = "Too High!"
        incrementGuesses()
    }
    else if UInt32(inputGuess!) < number{
        lblOutput.text = "Too Low!"
        incrementGuesses()
    }else{
        lblOutput.text = "Correct Guess! You Win!"
        guesses = 0
        txtInput.text = ""
        txtInput.enabled = false
        //btnGuess.enabled = false  //doesnt work

    }
}


@IBAction func btnStart(sender: UIButton) {

    number = generateRandom()
    lblOutput.text = "I'm thinking of a number between 0 - 100"
    lblGuesses.text = "0"
    txtInput.enabled = true
    //btnGuess.enabled = true  //doesnt work
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you're referencing (`btnGuess`) is declared as a function in your code here:

```
@IBAction func btnGuess(sender: UIButton) {
```

You may want to change the action function's name to `@IBAction func guess(sender: UIButton)` and then declare a `@IBOutlet weak var btnGuess: UIButton!` property.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because btnGuess is a function, not a variable.

Change this code:

```
@IBAction func btnGuess(sender:UIButton)
```

To:

```
@IBAction func btnGuessClicked(Sender:UIButton)
```

And also make an @IBOutlet for btnGuess.

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion will be to create also a:

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnGuess: UIButton!
```

in your view controller also attached to the same button and in the code add whenever relevant the line:

```
btnGuess.enabled = false
```

and that should do the trick for you

Answer (score 0):

You have the function of the button setup (the Action) but no way to reference the actual appearance of the button.

You need to add more IBOutlets at the top of your class for your buttons:

```
import UIKit

class myViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var btnStart: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var btnGuess: UIButton!

  @IBAction func btnStart(sender: UIButton) {
     btnGuess.enabled = true
  }

}
```