# Stop all UIButtons from working when I tap 1 UIButton swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to make it so that when I tap a UIButton, the rest of buttons are disabled until I click a refresh button.

I have 5 IBOutlets that I want to disable not including the refresh Button. Is there a function that stops the events that I can tie to the rest of the buttons? I don't even know where to start.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so I got it to work!  I did some more research and there's a duplicate of this post. Everything is explained here:

[Disable and Enable UIButton - XCode Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985027/disable-and-enable-uibutton-xcode-swift)

Thanks a lot anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Connects a method (IBAction) to the button that must disable other.
Within the method, for each button (connected in the GUI) type the follow line:

```
button.enabled = false
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I tried it and it gives me an error: (AnyObject) does not have a member named "enabled".

Comment: Have you assign the type UIButton in .h to the object you refer?

Comment: This is my code: ' @IBAction func one(sender: AnyObject) {
        one.enabled = false
      
    }' (This is in swift btw. ViewController.swift file not objective-c.

Comment: u can try: func one(sender: UIButton!)